# FindElements(By.tagName("a")) fails since one of the src having comma(,)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to find all the links in a page and store in a LIST.

But while reaching the below line, I get an exception as shown following the code.

```
elementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot use 'in'
>   operator to search for 'String' in ,

The reason is one of the attribute src contains a comma.
Please help me out.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to relate to the quoted code. Also, please post a [mcve] of the markup causing the problem and the code trying to work with that markup in which the problem occurs. (And just for what it's worth: Having a comma in an attribute value is not a problem.)

Comment: What happens when you use css?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. The head tag contains script like this ->  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= contextPath %>/js/msgs/I18nMsg,AjxMsg.js"></script>